# scala v2.9.2/OpenJDK 1.7 Class.getResourceAsStream always returning null

Tags: scala

I'm running scala from the command line like this

scala -classpath dir/my.jar

dir/my.jar contains a file /my-resource.xml.

In the scala REPL, I do this

classOf[Object].getResourceAsStream("/my-resource.xml")

But I always get back null. Any idea why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're asking the wrong classloader.  The classloader who loaded `java.lang.Object` is probably the boot classloader; he doesn't have access to your classes.

Try this:

```
classOf[MyOwnClass].getResourceAsStream(...)
```

Comment: I deleted my answer since Alex here explained it in more detail. Just one note since three_cups_of_java was asking about the REPL: you can use "getClass.getResourceAsStream("/my-resource.xml")"